# How change the initial value of an asp.net mvc DatePicker from format of "06/22/2019 00:00:00" to Persian format like 1398/04/01

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I started an asp.net mvc project and I have below html helper in my view :

```
@Html.Editor("From_Date"})
```

and I made this tag to work as Persian DatePicker with below jquery code :

```
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // create DatePicker from input HTML element
            $("#From_Date").kendoDatePicker();
        });
</script>
```

This html helper takes an initial value in format of "06/22/2019 00:00:00". It is too hard and too long to explain how it gets this initial value.
I wanna write a code with jquery to make this HTML helper to show this initial value to Persian format like 1398/04/01 when the document is ready(when the page is loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PersianCalendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.persiancalendar?view=netframework-4.8) from `System.Globalization` to convert the Gregorian date into a Persian date.

You can put the below code straight into your view.

```
@{
    var date = DateTime.Now;  // or from your model (Model.From_Date)
    var pc = new System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
    var persianDay = pc.GetDayOfMonth(date);
    var persianMonth = pc.GetMonth(date);
    var persianYear = pc.GetYear(date);

    // create the date string  for use in the date picker
    string persianDateString = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", persianYear, persianMonth, persianDay);
 }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#From_Date").kendoDatePicker({ format: "yyyy/MM/dd" });
    var datepicker = $("#From_Date").data("kendoDatePicker");
    datepicker.value('@persianDateString');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This method was good idea and I changed it according to my project

Comment: I have a big problem with this method that you sent me. When I choose a Persian date with datepicker e.g 1398/04/17 and I send request to server then the page will be refreshed and  the chosen date will be dropped by ten and convert to 1398/04/07. Why?

Comment: Does every date change to 1398/04/07 or is every date dropped by ten?  Just wondering because I think today's date is 1398/04/07 in the Persian calendar.  Could `DateTime.Now` be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use kendo date picker property like below to set the format you need -

```
$("#From_Date").kendoDatePicker({
    format: "yyyy/MM/dd",
    parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy"] });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but this answer had not solved my this problem but this can help me to solve my another problem. How can I make this datepicker to select hour and minute and second Except date